# JavaFX library - trying to add attributes not on offer

Tags: java, javafx

I am using a JavaFX library, [TilesFX](https://github.com/HanSolo/tilesfx). I am new to using libraries such as this. The library uses a builder class.

The builder allows properties to be added, for example a text property. I want to add a text field however, so when the user clicks on the text they can edit the contents.

The only way I can think to achieve this is by manually editing the library code to add in the text field class details.

This doesn't seem right to me, is there a better way of achieving this? Is it common for people to manipulate libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altering library code in your project is usually not a good idea.

This particular library releases a new version every few days. If you alter the code, you'll have a hard time upgrading to a new version, that might contain bug fixes or features you need.

If the library cannot be configured to the way you'd like to work, you can either try to find something else that does what you want, or try to contribute code to the library you're working with (or just do it yourself).

The way to go about it, is to [fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) the library, add the feature you want, and submit a [pull-request](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) to the library maintainers.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this process. I will look into these options.